# Upload file to onedrive using Graph API without showing authentication

Tags: api, graph, onedrive

We want to use OneDrive for storing all clients uploaded files in MVC project. We want to create a dedicated user to upload file. But we want to handle the onedrive authentication programmatically without Microsofts Onedrive login to popup asking user credentials.
The end user will select the file for upload, on upload button click, programmatically we want to authenticate using internal onedrive account and upload the file. End User will need to use their credentials when they try to open the file. 
Need the guidence on how to programmatically do authentication to onedrive. So far I have read that, the manual authentication is required at least once. Is there any way that we can avoid it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, were you able to do this? I have the same challenge and I need some help. Would you be able to help me out please?